# Centering buttons regardless of how many in list

Tags: html, css

I've created a relatively simple layout using two DIVs. The idea is that everything is centered within their own DIVs but if there's not enough to fill a row the ones below would center also.

```css
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5vh;
    margin-bottom: 2.5vh;
}

.item {
    width: 16.6%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
.item {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<div class="item">
    1
</div>

<div class="item">
    2
</div>

<div class="item">
    3
</div>

<div class="item">
    4
</div>

<div class="item">
    5
</div>

<div class="item">
    6
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

These work fine and are all aligned. The issue comes when there's an odd number of items.

For example:

`| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |`

Works fine on mobile but...

`| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |   |`

doesn't. I'd want something like this...

`| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|  4  |  5  |`

That means no matter how many items are added within the HTML they'll distribute properly when those rules are broken. Thanks in advance :)

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You should try [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using `Flexbox`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px Solid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
      1
  </div>

  <div class="item">
      2
  </div>

  <div class="item">
      3
  </div>

  <div class="item">
      4
  </div>

  <div class="item">
      5
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wdo8p1g/)

Comment: I understand why you've done this but it needs to work with the widths as percentages so it knows when to break

Comment: @learningtoanimate with percentage also it will work check the answer